# Detect a home button click with Safari on an iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, event-listener, home-button

Is it possible to listen for a 'home button' click when running a web app on an iPad?  Something equivalent to `applicationDidEnterBackground` for native iOS apps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect in iOS webapp when switching back to Safari from background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656387/how-to-detect-in-ios-webapp-when-switching-back-to-safari-from-background)

Comment: Also, check out [pagehide and pageshow events don't work as expected on ios chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311478/pagehide-and-pageshow-events-dont-work-as-expected-on-ios-chrome)