# pagehide and pageshow events don't work as expected on ios chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, dom-events

Apple documentation lists down the available iOS browser events here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

The 'pagehide' and 'pageshow' events seem to work fine on safari, but on chrome it only works on page load and unload. It doesn't work on:

1. Pressing the home button, i.e. sending Chrome to background
2. Switching tabs

Below is a small Javascript snippet that you can use to verify it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(evt){
            alert('show');
        }, false);
        window.addEventListener("pagehide", function(evt){
            alert('hide');
        }, false);
</script>
```

What can I do to detect whether chrome was sent to background or not. I need to clear a setTimeout timer as soon as chrome is brought back to foreground. Any workarounds?

Comment: I don't think you understand what 'pageshow' and 'pagehide' are meant to be for.  They happen (a) on load/unload, and (b) on changing whether the page is the current page in the browser's history cache (i.e. when you navigate away or back to the page).  They have NOTHING TO DO with whether the browser window is VISIBLE.  They aren't meant to fire in your cases (1) and (2).

Comment: @Doin even if I take your word for it (though a link to documentation will help), why is the behaviour different than Safari? Safari fires those events in the scenarios I described. At least one of them is buggy.

Comment: **Perhaps** minimizing Safari under iOS actually puts the page in the history cache and closes it (like navigating away would) to save CPU and/or RAM)? Anyway, some references: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-pagehide https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pagehide https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/client-side-javascript-reference/pagetransitionevent ; ...and the apple link you provided clearly states that pagehide/show are preferred replacements for the (*non*visual) unload/load events.

Comment: This page describes in detail the rationale behind the pageshow/hide events:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching

Comment: At least one of those browsers is showing incorrect (inconsistent w.r.t web development) behavior, and therefore requires special handling.

Comment: Well possibly. All browsers differ from each other in some ways. But I *speculate* that it's what I already suggested: That on iOS devices, Safari is "freezing" its open webpage into the cache whenever it gets minimized or switches tabs, to save limited RAM & CPU resources on those devices. This has the effect of (correctly) triggering pageshow/hide.  Whereas Chrome is probably just behaving More like a desktop browser and leaving the pages open and running... or at least, not doing the full close-and-cache that'd trigger those events. Neither is necessarily wrong. What does desktop Safari do?

Comment: >> "What does desktop Safari do?"  
Cannot verify that - I use linux. The question is specific to iOS devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is the working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var heartbeat;
        var lastInterval;

        function clearTimers() {
            clearTimeout(heartbeat);
        }

        function getTime() {
            return (new Date()).getTime();
        }

        function intervalHeartbeat() {
            var now = getTime();
            var diff = now - lastInterval - 200;
            lastInterval = now;
            if(diff > 1000) { // don't trigger on small stutters less than 1000ms
                clearTimers();
            }
        }
        lastInterval = getTime();
        heartbeat = setInterval(intervalHeartbeat, 200);
```

You can find more details here: http://aawaara.com/post/74543339755/smallest-piece-of-code-thats-going-to-change-the-world

Comment: The fact that this works at all (assuming I take your word that it in fact does), means that javascript timers are not being triggered on background tabs or while the browser is minimized.  So you may as well call `clearTimers()` earlier, when the browser tab is sent to the background rather then when it returns to the foreground, if you can detect that.  Also (I assume you realize?), on any desktop browser, the above code will NEVER call `clearTimers()`:  These browsers continue running JS timers/events/code even in background tabs or when minimized.

Comment: It works for me. And yes, I use that only on iOS devices by detecting that server side.

Comment: For Chrome on iOS this 'heartbeat' approach seems to be the only working solution, as `visibilitychange` doesn't fire on iOS Chrome (similar to `pageshow/pagehide` not firing).

Answer (score 2):

Pagehide and pageshow aren't the events you need for what you're trying to accomplish.

Instead, use the `visibilitychange` event in combination with `document.hidden` or `document.visibilitystate`, which should do exactly what you want.

This'll only work on supported browsers - which to date includes Chrome, but not Safari (yet).  So to be safe, I'd call `clearTimers()` on `visibilitychange`, and fall back to calling it on `pagehide` only if document.visibilitystate is not defined.

See:

[MDN: visibilitychange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange)

[MDN: Using the Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API)

[Page Visibility - W3C recommendation, October 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/)

Comment: Page visibility API has poor (not so good) browser support, and I had to spend effort trying to make it work across all browsers. You can find more details here: http://aawaara.com/post/88310470252/smallest-piece-of-code-thats-going-to-change-the

Comment: After upvoting this answer, I found out that the `visibilitychange` events suffer the same issue in iOS Chrome as the `pageshow/pagehide` events: NO EVENT IS FIRED on iOS Chrome on e.g. home key press, or deeplinking into an app/store. Amit's heartbeat solution that relies on timers clamping to 1000ms in backgrounded tabs seems to be a good workaround. I'd personally use a timeout over interval (intervals have the additional overhead of needing to be cleared vs. setTimeout callback function can have a condition that either clears the redirectTimer or sets a new timeout to call itself again).

Comment: I take back my suggestion to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. During testing of my setTimeout implementation, on iOS Chrome, after coming back to the tab, my 100ms 'heartbeat' timeout would often fire only after the 2000ms timer that I wanted to cancel in the heartbeat callback (usually about 20-70ms too late). A `setInterval` implementation seems to consistently fire before the long timeout is triggered, which is what we want.